# Why my publish app can't receive the push notification of apns,it works on the developer version?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I found that the publish app can't receive the device token.I can't find the device token in my server.But the develop version can do this.

This is my register code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |      UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken

{

NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDir=[paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *myFM=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *filepath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"devicetoken.plist"];

if([myFM fileExistsAtPath:filepath]==NO){

NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dic setObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"DeviceToken"] forKey:@"type"];

[dic setObject:[NSString stringWithString:@""] forKey:@"_id"];

[dic setObject:str forKey:@"token"];

CJSONDeserializer * jo=[[CJSONDataSerializer alloc]autorelease];

NSData *data=[jo serializeDictionary:dic];

NSURL* url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:url]];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/json"];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:data];

putDoc = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember:
The push certificate in the Apple Developer Portal (under provisioning / application) must be created before the app built and signed.

So i would recommend:
-> check in the provisioning portal -> application if the production push certificate is proper created
-> re-build the app store provisioning file
-> re-build the app with the re-buil prov. file

-> upload again a update to the app store

Jonas

Comment: Yes the push certificate is created after the distribute provison file.I think it's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you still use the push notification development profile ?
If not, change it to the production profile.